# IntelliJ IDEA method name indentation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Consider I have a verbose method declaration, so I want to wrap method name so line with method declaration is not too long:

```
private Map<VeryLongClassName, VeryLongClassName>
    veryLongMethodName(...
```

IDEA's autoformatting does not indent method name relatively to class members:

```
 private Map<VeryLongClassName, VeryLongClassName>
 veryLongMethodName(...
```

I however want it to be indented like in the first code snippet.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such option yet. You can follow and vote for this feature request: [IDEA-185677](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185677), which is titled "An option to apply continuation indent to method name" and describes what you want.